# Cookie write fails to work on hosted site

Tags: cookies, setcookie, missing-cookies

I have created a basic but extensive javascript-html page that depends on cookies to keep user information. It runs perfectly on my computer (MAC - Firefox) but when loaded into my hosted web site (the page is in my domain) the cookies are not being written when  the page is opened.

I was hoping that by keeping all the programming in javascript I could get some basic interactivity. Is this assumption wrong?  Must the cookies be written using PHP?

My cookie writes are very vanilla.

```
document.cookie = cookieArray[ja]+expires+"; path=/"; // writes cookie data into browser.
```

**update**

well cookies are now being written since I added `"path=/; domain=.my.org"`. But now there is one other problem. 
It seems that safari and Firefox write the cookies in reverse order to each other. I create the cookies by altering an array then simply stepping thru the array to write the cookies. I was hoping that I could simply read the cookies one by one and keep the order. Ah well.

Comment: If you find the answer yourself, then post it as a proper answer and mark it as accepted, rather than editing your question and putting "solved" at the start.

Answer (score 0):

Did you added the ";" between cookieArray[ja] and expires?

```
document.cookie = 'cookie-name=cookie-value; expires=Thu, 01-Jan-70 00:00:01 GMT;';
```

Also the cookieArray[ja] have to contain the cookie-name.

Do you really need the path? This parameter is also optional.

> Cookies are, by default, available to all other files in the same directory the cookie was created in.

http://www.comptechdoc.org/independent/web/cgi/javamanual/javacookie.html

Comment: thanks, cookieArray[ja]  contains  cookie-name=data and expires contains the ;-- works on local but not hosted.